# How to set filter in columnDefs property in angular UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have angular ui grid in application and I want a field to be hide if any field value is null or empty.

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        columnDefs: [
          { displayName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
          { displayName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
          { displayName: 'Active Status', field: 'activeStatus', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
          { displayName: 'RoleName', field: 'roleName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
        ]
    };
```

How to put a filter in field. Suppose if my **rolename** in above code is empty/null then hide the role field from grid.

Any help and suggestion highly appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Not able to find the solution. Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I fixed it.

```
var result = [];
var gridValue= [
      { displayName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
      { displayName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
      { displayName: 'Active Status', field: 'activeStatus', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
      { displayName: 'RoleName', field: 'roleName', headerCellClass: "GridHeader" },
    ];
```

in the response I checked for null value.

```
if(response.data != null)
{
    if (response.data.roleName === null) {
        result = gridValue.slice(0, 3);
    }
    else {
        result = gridValue;
    }
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        paginationPageSize: 10,
        columnDefs: result,
     };
}
```

this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using

```
that.grid.columnDefs[3].visible = false;
```

I haven't tested, but it should be more efficient than removing the column from your definition and re-applying the definition to the grid.

I think you could also set the visibility as a function that checks the data.

```
that.grid.columnDefs[3].visible = function () { 
    // replace with code checking grid.data
    return false;
}
```